# How to get subcollection after groupCollection()?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a chat app on iOS using firestore. I can't figure out how to get a subcollection after doing groupCollection().

The database structure is

```
users (collection)
  some_user_info
  conversations (collection)
    some_conversation_info
    messages (collection)
```

If A and B have a conversation and A sends a message to B, what I did is I create a conversation with the same id for both A and B, but only store that message to A. (Who sends it, who owns it)

So when fetching all messages between A and B, I have to do

```
db.collectionGroup("conversations").whereField("id", isEqualTo: conversationId)
```

But it seems there is no way to fetch messages collection after group query on conversations. Is there any walkaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a collection group, by definition, includes an unlimited number of individual collections of the same name, it doesn't make sense to simply address another single subcollection under that.  If you want to query a specific messages subcollection under a specific document that comes back from a collection group query, you can certainly build that in your code, but you will need its DocumentReference to build that.

Or, maybe you want to do a collection group query on messages, you can do that as long as you're able to filter that with the fields of the documents you're looking for.

Comment: How to get DocumentReference? Group collection returns a Query, and there is no way to turn a Query to Reference, right? But you are right, I am going to restructure the db. Still not used to design nosql database. Thanks!

Comment: You can get one from an individual DocumentSnapshot.

Comment: That helps a lot! Thank you!